Unable to reinstall Play Store
I am using a Galaxy S23 and have been using ADB to remove apps from it.
Previously I have been able to uninstall and reinstall the Play Store fine, but this time it is giving me the error:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package
com.android.vending signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]

This is after running these two commands:
adb shell pm uninstall com.android.vending
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.vending

The signatures remain on the phone even after uninstalling Play Store, and this is for onboard APK and ADB installs.

Have you tried adb shell cmd package install-existing com.android.vending ?

You gave me the right answer dude
